# Meta Box Value not saving / populating?

Tags: metabox

Ok, I have a meta box setup now that populates with the all the registered post types.  That part works fine.  But, upon selecting an option in the dropdown list, and saving / updating, the value shows the first choice when the page reloads.  Also, does anyone know if get_post_types can exclude specific post types?

Here's my code:

```
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
    function cd_meta_box_add()
    {
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
    }

    function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
    {
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
$selected = isset( $values['my_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_select'][0] ) : '';
wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>

<p>
    <label for="my_meta_box_select">Post type: </label>
    <select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select">
        <?php $post_types=get_post_types('', 'objects'); foreach ($post_types as $post_type): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($post_type->name);?>"  <?php selected( $selected, '$post_type->name' ); ?>><?php echo esc_html($post_type->label); selected ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</p>    


<?php   
    }


    add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
    function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
    {
// Bail if we're doing an auto save
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

// if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

// now we can actually save the data
$allowed = array( 
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags
        'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
    )
);

// Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set

if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables do not expand inside single quotes, so this-- `selected( $selected, '$post_type->name'`-- is literally checking for a string that looks like '$post_type->name'. If you are saving the option names, it should work if you just remove the quotes (though I did not run your code to test that).

Your *might* be able to exclude what you want via the `public` and `_builtin` arguments to [`get_post_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types), but if you are looking to exclude a particular type other than what those arguments will do, I don't see a way to do that directly, but [there is a filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L1120). It would likely be easier just to filter the post type out in your `foreach` loop though.

Comment: Awesome!  That was exactly what I needed!  I'd vote your answer up, but I don't have the rep.

Comment: OK, I have one more question related to the code above.  I need to call the value from the dropdown and place it in a query.  How would you go about adding the value from the drop down to the query code below: 
        <?php $wp_query->query("post_type=nemultispecies&paged=".$paged.'&showposts=5'); ?>

Comment: Use `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', true);`, if I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, I tried this code but I don't think it's working out for me:   <?php $wp_query->query("post_type=<?php get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', true); ?>&paged=".$paged.'&showposts=5'); ?>

Comment: Got it!  

    <?php $cpt = get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_meta_box_select", true); ?>
     
  <?php $temp = $wp_query;
 $wp_query= null;
 $wp_query = new WP_Query(); ?>
  <?php $wp_query->query("post_type= '.$cpt.'&paged=".$paged.'&showposts=5'); ?>